# Branching coverage failing due to a timeout logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have the following implementation where upon clicking a button, some text is added to clipboard.

After a 5 second period state is changed and user can click the button again to copy.

The logic is working fine and written the test where I have 100% line coverage.

But not meeting branch and statement coverage. After investigating issue is due to this line.

```
setTimeout(() => setCopyStatus(''), 5000);
```

If I comment this out just to test, I get 100% test coverage for all.

Since I have met the line coverage. Unable to understand what I should do here to meet the coverage expectations.

Could I get some advice on how to target this to write a test to get the branch coverage.

This is the component.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button } from '../../Button';

const A = ({
 text,
}) => {
  const [copyStatus, setCopyStatus] = useState('');

  const sleep = () => {
    // issue is with this line. If I comment this out, I get full coverage.
    setTimeout(() => setCopyStatus(''), 5000);
  };

  const onClick = () => {
    window.navigator.clipboard.writeText(text)
      .then(() => {
        setCopyStatus('yes');
        sleep();
      })
      .catch(() => setCopyStatus('no'));
  };

  const CopyBtn = () => (
    <Button onClick={onClick}>
      Click
    </Button>
  );

  return (<div>
    {CopyBtn}
  </div>);
};

export default A;
```

This is the current test which all passes and but as mentioned not meeting branch coverage.

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import A from '../../../src/components/A';

jest.mock('../../Button', () => ({
  Button: 'button',
}));

describe('A component test', () => {
  const props = {
    text: 'mock',
  };

  it('should copy to clipboard as expected', () => {
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'clipboard', {
      configurable: true,
      value: {
        writeText: jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(Promise.resolve()),
      },
    });
    const renderedModule = mount(<A {...props} />);
    renderedModule.find('button').simulate('click');
    expect(navigator.clipboard.writeText).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(navigator.clipboard.writeText).toHaveBeenCalledWith('expectedCopy');
  });

  it('should throw error on attempt to copy to clipboard', () => {
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'clipboard', {
      configurable: true,
      value: {
        writeText: jest.fn().mockRejectedValue(new Error()),
      },
    });
    const renderedModule = mount(<CopyLink {...props} />);
    renderedModule.find('button').simulate('click');
    expect(navigator.clipboard.writeText).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(renderedModule.find('div.error').at(0).exists()).toBeTruthy();
  });

  // some other tests where I try without text value other redux tests not related to issue. 
});
```

Comment: You probably need to use `Timer mocks`: https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks. Then advance the timer by 5 seconds after simulating the click event on the button.